# Easy SQL Query - Aligning foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I'm taking longer than I expected with an easy Query in MySQL. I think it's gonna be a nested query but I don't see it easily.

I have 3 tables: Users, Comments, and Businesses. Comments have business_id, and user_id as foreign keys.

So I want the result of users.name and comments.review, having the number of the business.

So my First (and wrong) attempt was:

```
SELECT users.name, users.image, comments.review 
FROM reviews JOIN users JOIN businesses 
WHERE reviews.user_id=users.id AND reviews.business_id=4;
```

I want to set that PrimaryKey.user_id is equal to ForeignKey.users.id.
From all of the comments, I want to take these which are from the business_id=4.

It gives me failiure with both 'WHERE' clauses. So not sure if I could fix this with a nested query or maybe with a JOIN clause?

Any help will be appreciated! 
Thank you all. [Edited Query]

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You should fix the query in your question.

Comment: Each JOIN needs an ON clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and let me know in case of any queries.

```
select c.name,c.image,a.review
from
comments a
inner join
(select * from buisnesses where buisness_id = 4) b
on a.buisness_id = b.buisness_id 
inner join
users c
on a.user_id = c.user_id;
```

or

```
select b.name,b.image,a.review
from
comments a
inner join
users b
on a.user_id = b.user_id  
where a.buisness_id = 4;
```

Comment: Lovin' it! It worked! 

I didn't know using INNER or JOIN clauses :/ and separating FROM with commas always worked to me, I saw it in many places.. to my mind!

Thanks a lot! :')

Comment: As told by @gordan linoff , you should never use commas in from statement. Moreover, chances of making mistakes are also less while writing different joins. In this case writing "where" condition before rather than at the end also saves processing time. And you are welcome

Comment: @Suzena MySQLs engine will use the conditions from the WHERE clause as soon as possible. So no - there is no point in wrapping the condition in a subquery.

Comment: Using subqueries unnecessarily in MySQL is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    users.name, 
    users.image, 
    comments.review 
FROM reviews 
JOIN users 
ON reviews.user_id = users.id
JOIN businesses 
ON reviews.business_id = business.business_id
WHERE reviews.business_id=4;
```

Since you're not using any of the columns from the business table, you could probably drop it from the query:

```
SELECT 
    users.name, 
    users.image, 
    comments.review 
FROM reviews 
JOIN users 
ON reviews.user_id = users.id
WHERE reviews.business_id=4;
```

Comment: This is much the better answer, although I would prefer to see it use table aliases.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks. Since the OP is new, I thought I'd keep it simple. I also prefer alias on tables.

Comment: Thanks you all! This last code also worked to me, and its even clearer and shorter.
Thanks for the quick response!